# Azure DevOps send parameters from pipeline to powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I tried to find some information in internet. But unfortunately I could not found any information.
Im trying to send pipeline parameters from pipeline into powershell script

pipeline below:

```
parameters:
    - name: env
      displayName: Select Environment
      type: string
      default: development
    
stages:
- stage: test
  displayName: test var
  jobs:
  - job: PostgresSQL
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          filePath: '$(5ystem. DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test.psl'
          errorActionPreference: 'continue'
        enabled: true
```

I need to send **${{ parameters.env }}** to powershell.
I tried different type of define param like a variable into powershell. but it does not work.

I would be very happy if anybody can help me and share relevant documentation for that.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

First approach is to provide arguments using 'arguments' keyword (available in PowerShell by 'param')

```
filePath: xyz
arguments: -input1 ${{ parameters.env }}
```

documentation and example - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines#call-powershell-script-with-multiple-arguments

Second approach you can map parameters to environment variables provided to script using 'env' keyword

```
env:
  input1: ${{ parameters.env }}
```

documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#environment-variables

Comment: This is the best answer. The only thing that's missing is that you could "inline" your PowerShell, but that's frankly a bit of a trap that I'd recommend avoiding.